# OrbitControls not working with Loading file

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

So I have this code which basically shows a 3D file (obj, stl, 3mf) inputted by the user using three js OBJLoader, STLLoader, and 3MFLoader. All works fine but I tried some (inside this code) to add OrbitControls to this so that the user can zoom in, zoom out, rotate, etc. with the file but it does not seem to work. The console has no errors at all but rotating, zooming in and out, etc. doesn't work as well with the render.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" />
<div id="filePreview" style="width: 100%; height: 30vh"></div>
<script>
  var loadFile = function (event) {
    let oInput = document.getElementById("file");
    var _validFileExtensions = [".obj", ".stl", ".3mf"];
    function ValidateSingleInput() {
      if (oInput.type == "file") {
        var sFileName = oInput.value;
        if (sFileName.length > 0) {
          var blnValid = false;
          for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
            var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
            if (
              sFileName
                .substr(
                  sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length,
                  sCurExtension.length
                )
                .toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()
            ) {
              window.fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
              var scene = new THREE.Scene();

              var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                75,
                window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
                0.1,
                1000
              );

              var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

              const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement, scene );

              camera.position.z = 200;
              controls.update();

              var scene = new THREE.Scene();

              var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                45,
                window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
                1,
                2000
              );
              camera.position.z = 250;
              camera.lookAt(scene.position);
              controls.update();

              var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffeedd);
              directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 1).normalize();
              scene.add(directionalLight);

              var mesh = null;
              if (sCurExtension == ".obj") {
                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.load(window.fileUrl, function (object) {
                  mesh = object;
                  mesh.position.y = -50;
                  scene.add(mesh);
                });
              } else if (sCurExtension == ".3mf") {
                var loader = new THREE.ThreeMFLoader();
                loader.load(window.fileUrl, function (object) {
                  mesh = object;
                  mesh.position.y = -50;
                  scene.add(mesh);
                });
              } else if (sCurExtension == ".stl") {
                var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
                loader.load(window.fileUrl, function (geometry) {
                  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    specular: 0x111111,
                    shininess: 200,
                    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                  });
                  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                  mesh.position.y = -50;
                  scene.add(mesh);
                });
              }

              renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
              renderer.setSize(
                filePreview.offsetWidth,
                filePreview.offsetHeight
              );

              renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
              document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

              animate();

              function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                controls.update();

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
              }

              filePreview.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
              blnValid = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (!blnValid) {
            alert(
              "Sorry, " +
                sFileName +
                " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " +
                _validFileExtensions.join(", ")
            );
            oInput.value = "";
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    }

    ValidateSingleInput();
  };
</script>

<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/3MFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
```

Can anyone check the code out and tell me why it is not working and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you loading Three.js from a script tag or with a bundler/compiler?

Comment: @Enijar I am using script tag with CDN, sorry I forgot to include in question.

Comment: @Enijar included now, please tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OrbitControls` is not directly exported as part of the Three.js library; instead it's exported as part of the `examples`.

If you're using a bundler (such as WebPack) you can import it like this:

```js
// Typical Three.js import
import * as THREE from "three"

// Additional OrbitControls import
import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
```

Or if you're using a script import, you can use this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js";
  import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  );
  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  camera.position.z = 5;

  (function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  })();
</script>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```js
const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement, scene );
```

Comment: Good answer for that case, but I am using a script tag with CDN.

Comment: Is there a way for that? Also, I did include it but it doesn't give any error nor does it work.

Comment: See my code in the question.

Comment: @Stranger I've updated my answer to include a script import

Comment: You see OrbitControls IS NOT GIVING ANY ERRORS so it is loaded and initialized correctly (probably). The problem is that while IT's not giving any errors it is not working as well. I try rotating the view, nothing, zoom in zoom out, nothing. Any comments?

Comment: Did you see my code? do you think why It might not be working?

Comment: @Stranger I'm pulling together an example to link you to – bare with me

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: @Stranger I've added a run-time example to my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you so much for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

```js
controls.mouseButtons = {
        LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
        MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY,
        RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).