# How do i import OrbitControls in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to import OrbitControls but it isnt working.
I imported three.js and then tried impoting OrbitControls but it isnt working
I imported three.js in the body of the html with this command
***`script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/104/three.js"`***
NOTE: I do have a scene and a camera and a renderer but i cant post this post with them here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/master.css">
</head>
<body>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/104/three.js"></script>
   <script src="Main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
  ***Main.js***
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/example/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
   
   
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        torus.rotation.x +=0.01;
        torus.rotation.y +=0.01;
        torus.rotation.z +=0.01;
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    }
    animate()
```

Comment: I believe that question was just asked a few hours ago. Here’s a good answer: [OrbitControls not working with Loading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841333/orbitcontrols-not-working-with-loading-file) just make sure you add type=“module” to your <script>tag so it can handle import statements.

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: See my answer... it should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `jsm` version of the OrbitControls, which means that you need a module for the Javascript file. Change:

`<script src="Main.js"></script>`

to

`<script type="module" src="Main.js"></script>`

That should do the trick.